# How to upcast an object of type IEnumerable<Foo> to IEnumerable<IFoo> if passed to the function as object?

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I'm trying to upcast a parameter passed as an object (which is an upcast of an object of type IEnumerable) to IEnumerable where Foo implements IFoo.

Here is an example of what I'd like to do but it does not work.

```
public void F(object o)
{
    //I know the object o is of type IEnumerable<Foo> where Foo implements IFoo
    IEnumerable<IFoo> ifoos = (IEnumerable<IFoo>) o);
}
```

Is there a work around? I don't want to make the function F Foo specific but I cannot get it to cast to the Interface Unless I do:

```
IEnumerable<IFoo> ifoos = (IEnumerable<Foo>) o).Select( f => (IFoo) f);
```

Thanks

Giuseppe

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Before .NET 4.0, you can't - `IEnumerable<T>` is *invariant* before .NET 4.0.

With .NET 4.0, the code you've posted will work fine.

In .NET 3.5 you could use `Enumerable.Cast`:

```
public void F(object o)
{
    IEnumerable<IFoo> ifoos = ((IEnumerable) o).Cast<IFoo>();
}
```

Basically this uses the weakly typed `IEnumerable` (which both `IEnumerable<Foo>` and `IEnumerable<IFoo>` extend, so the cast will be fine) and then applies the `Cast<T>` method, which will basically chain another iterator to perform a cast on each item. That cast will certainly work if `Foo : IFoo`, so you'll be fine.

In .NET 2.0 you'd have to basically write `Cast` yourself, which is easy enough - particularly if you don't need to do any shortcuts:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Cast<TSource, TResult>
    (IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    foreach(TSource item in source)
    {
        yield return (TResult) (object) item;
    }
}
```

The double cast is slightly awkward, but it works...

Comment: More info on covariance/contravariance in .NET 4: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233054%28VS.100%29.aspx and related topics in the table at the bottom.

Comment: Or by the early access 2nd edition of C# in Depth and read chapter 13 :) (http://manning.com/skeet2)

Comment: Incredibly quick reply, spot on THANK YOU!

Comment: Sorry, that should be "buy" not "by" obviously :)

Answer (score 1):

Would a generic method be acceptable?

```
interface IFoo { }
class Foo : IFoo { }
static void F<T>(IEnumerable<T> data) where T : IFoo
{ 
    foreach(T item in data) {
       // compiler knows that `item` is an `IFoo` etc
    }
}

...
List<Foo> foos = new List<Foo>();
F(foos);
```

Otherwise; wait until .NET 4.0 / C# 4.0 / VS2010.

Comment: It would if I were creating the function for scratch but I'm tweaking the body of an existing function so that it can handle other types that implement IFoo.